# Why the inverse of $ L\in Pic(X) $ is the dual bundle?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Given $ L\in Pic(X) $, the inverse of $ L $, denoted by $ L^{*} $ is the dual bundle $ Hom(L, \mathbb{C}) $, the transition functions of $ L^{*} $ are $ \{ g_{\alpha\beta}^{-1}, U_{\alpha} \} $. And we know that the unit element of $ Pic(X) $ is the trivial line bundle $ X\times\mathbb{C} $. But how to prove that $ L\otimes L^{*}\cong X\times\mathbb{C} $ ? And I am confused about the definition of the dual line bundle $ L^{*} $, for example how to define the topology of $ 
L^{*} $ ?

Comment: A line bundle is trivial iff it has a section. $L \otimes L^*$ has a section, since $L \otimes L^* \cong Hom(L, L)$, and the latter has the identity section. Another way to prove it is to show that when you tensor two line bundles, their transition data multiplies. Regarding questions of topology, this may help: https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~azinger/mat566-spr15/vectorbundles.pdf

Comment: Just to make a small correction to the above comment. A line bundle is trivial if and only if it has a nowhere vanishing section. Having a section is not enough.

Comment: @Mohan Oops, thanks. Of course you are right. (For 'A beginer' every line bundle has a section, namely the zero section.)