# Is the Picard group of a smooth manifold the same as the Picard group of the associated ringed space?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, line-bundles, picard-group

$\def\sO{\mathcal{O}}
\def\Pic{\operatorname{Pic}}$Given a ringed space $(X,\sO_X)$, the Picard group of $(X,\sO_X)$ is defined to be the class of isomorphism classes of invertible sheaves of $\sO_X$-modules with the tensor product of sheaves of modules as group operation (defined in [01CX](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01CX)). We denote it by $\Pic(X,\sO_X)$.

On the other hand, if $M$ is a smooth manifold, there is another notion of Picard group for $M$. Namely, the class of isomorphism classes of smooth line bundles over $M$ with the tensor product of bundles as group operation (the inverse is given by the dual bundle, as it is explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862023/why-the-inverse-of-l-in-picx-is-the-dual-bundle)). We denote it by $\Pic(M)$.

However, $M$ is naturally a (locally) ringed space with its sheaf $\sO_M$ of real-valued smooth functions. So my question is: is $\Pic(M)\cong\Pic(M,\sO_M)$?

Comment: That's sometimes called Serre-Swan theorem which states that equivalence of category of rank $n$ vector bundle and locally free sheaf of constant rank $n$

Comment: @yili I guess it depends on what you call the "Serre-Swan theorem". The SST I know for smooth vector bundles over a smooth manifold $M$ is the one stated on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%E2%80%93Swan_theorem#Differential_geometry), which says that the _global sections_ functor is an equivalence of categories into finitely generated projective $C^\infty(M)$-modules. The object I am interested on my question is the _sheaf of sections_ of a vector bundle, not only the global sections.

Comment: Ok the SST that I mean is also about sheaf of section. I don't know what wiki want to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\VB{\mathsf{VB}}
\def\LFMod{\mathsf{LFMod}}
\def\bbR{\mathbb{R}}
\def\op{\oplus}
\def\sO{\mathcal{O}}
$The answer is yes. First note that over a locally ringed space (as $(M,\sO_M)$ is) invertible modules are the same as locally free of finite rank 1 modules (see [0B8M](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B8M)).

The isomorphism between Picard groups is induced by the functor
\begin{align*}
\Sigma:\VB(M)&\to\LFMod(\sO_M)\\
E&\mapsto\Sigma_E\\
F:E\to E'&\mapsto F_*:\Sigma_E\to\Sigma_{E'},
\end{align*}
from the category of vector bundles over $M$ to the category of locally finite free sheaves of $\sO_M$-modules. Here $\Sigma_E$ is the $\sO_M$-module of sections of the vector bundle $E$, and $F_*$ is the $\sO_M$-linear map induced by postcomposition with $F$. This functor is an equivalence of categories (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4627208/394668)). We are going to show that this functor preserves the monoidal structures given by the tensor product of vector bundles and of sheaves of $\sO_M$-modules,
$$
\Sigma_E\otimes_{\sO_M}\Sigma_{E'}\cong\Sigma_{E\otimes E'}.
$$
This map is constructed applying the universal property of the tensor product of $\sO_M$-modules to the $\sO_M$-bilinear map $\Sigma_E\oplus\Sigma_{E'}\to\Sigma_{E\otimes E'}$ which maps a section $(\sigma,\sigma')$ over $U$ to $\sigma\otimes\sigma':U\to E\otimes E'$. To see that it is an iso, it suffices to prove it locally, so one can assume $E=M\times \bbR^k$ and $E'=M\times \bbR^{k'}$. Then $E\otimes E' = M\times(\bbR^k\otimes_\bbR\bbR^{k'})\cong M\times\bbR^{kk'}$ and we have a commutative diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Sigma_E\otimes_{\sO_M}\Sigma_{E'} @>>> \Sigma_{E\otimes E'} \\
@V{\cong}VV @VV{\cong}V \\
\sO_M^{\op k}\otimes_{\sO_M}\sO_M^{\op k'} @>>> \sO_M^{\op kk'} 
\end{CD}
$$
The bottom map is just the distributivity of the tensor product of $\sO_M$-modules with respect to direct sums, which is an iso; hence, the top map is an iso.

On the other hand, $\Sigma$ restricts to an equivalence of categories between the full subcategories of vector bundles of a fixed rank $k$ and the locally free $\sO_M$-modules of rank $k$. In our case, for $k=1$ it induces an isomorphism between Picard groups, for it also preserves the identity element, $\Sigma_{M\times\mathbb{R}}\cong\mathcal{O}_M$.